# When I enter password to login, it returns login desktop inspite of correct password

Tags: login, login-screen

How to login my Ubuntu? I want to login to my Ubuntu desktop. When it is turned on and ask for enter password for specific user I add password keyboad and hit return key, but again it return login screen inspite of correct password. How to login to my desktop? Has the OS crashed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand, the password you enters seems to be wrong. Have you forgot it ?
You can reset you password that way

- Start you computer.
- Choose `Other options` and then `recovery mode`.
- Choose `root terminal` and then enter `passwd your_username`.
- Enter `reboot`.